# Accidentally erased 14.04-4 ubuntu and installed 14.04-1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I accidentally erased my Ubuntu 14.04-4 version and installed old one. Now I'm not able to access my windows 10 partitions.

I ran the `sudo fdisk -l` command and this is the terminal output:

[image: screenshot]

I need help, there are many important files in my windows 10 partition.

Thanks in advance.

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1 vfat         /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4         /
└─sda3 swap         [SWAP]
sr0
```

Comment: The output of `lsblk -f` would probably be more helpful... Could you please [edit] your question to add that? Also, it would be nice if you could copy the output (select it with your mouse in the terminal, right-click and chose "Copy") and pasted it here as plain text, using code formatting (**`{}`** button in the question editor) instead of posting a screenshot. Thank you and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've edited the question as u asked.

Comment: If your hdd is not larger than 3 TB, it seems that you wiped it out completely before installing Ubuntu. Windows usually installs to ntfs partition. No ntfs there. You may try a brute-force recovery of the lost ntfs partition, but it's a long shot (because you reformatted that space with another partition type: ext4, vfat).

Comment: So tell me what to do now ? I dont want to do a recovery. Can you point me to the correct tutorial of windows installation over existing ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your /dev/sdb1 mounted? If not, create a directory (i would suggest that you create it in `/media/(your username)`) and then run `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /path/to/the/directory`

Also, if you want Ubuntu to mount your Windows filesystem everytime it starts up, add the filesystem entry to /etc/fstab.